# копирование файлов с одинаковыми именами

Tags: c#

Программа выполняет копирование с одной папки в другую. Как добавить индекс, если существуют файлы с одинаковыми именами
Пробовал так

```
 int index = 1;
        string str = "" + index++;
        string source = @""C:\Users\101";
        string dest = @""C:\Users\102";
        DirectoryInfo dr = new DirectoryInfo(source);
        FileInfo[] fl = dr.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo file in fl)
        {
            File.Copy(source + @"\" + file.Name, dest + @"\" + file.Name.Replace(file.Name, str + file.Name));
        }
```

Если имена файлов одинаковые, ловит Exception "такой файл существует"

Comment: Если файл действительно существует, должно быть исключение. Если хотите его перезаписать, используйте File.Copy(oldFile, newFile, true)

Comment: *Как добавить индекс, если существуют файлы с одинаковыми именами* Поясните эту фразу. Можно примером.

Comment: Скопировал файлы тест001, тест002,тест003  в другую папку, через некоторое время в первой папке появляются файлы такие же тест001, тест002,тест003, мне нужно чтобы они переименовывались в тест004 ит.д.

Comment: А что должно произойти если в обеих папках есть файлы тест002, но при этом нет файлов тест001?

Comment: вы можете проверить есть ли в папке, в которую копируете такой файл. Если есть, то либо заменить его, либо в скопировать с другим уникальным именем.

Comment: Как вариант, при копировании добавлять к именам файлов _префикс_ в виде даты-времени.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если условие предусматривает то, что папки уже созданы и существуют, а также:

- при существовании копируемого файла с таким же именем в папке `dest` к нему
  добавляется постфикс 1, если и такой существует, то 2 и т.д.
- при существовании файла `dest/тест`, `dest/тест1`, `dest/тест3` копия
  будет иметь имя `dest/тест2`.

то одно из возможных решений будет следующим:

```
string source = @"D:\test";
string dest = @"D:\test2";
DirectoryInfo dr = new DirectoryInfo(source);
FileInfo[] fl = dr.GetFiles();

foreach (FileInfo file in fl)
{
    var destFilePath = dest + @"\" + file.Name;

    var postfix = 1;
    while (File.Exists(destFilePath))
    {
        var fileNameNoExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(destFilePath);
        var fileExt = Path.GetExtension(destFilePath);

        if (postfix == 1)
            destFilePath = dest + @"\" + fileNameNoExt + postfix + fileExt;                   
        else
            destFilePath = dest + @"\" + fileNameNoExt.Remove(fileNameNoExt.Length - postfix.ToString().Length) + postfix + fileExt;

        postfix++;
    }

    File.Copy(source + @"\" + file.Name, destFilePath);
}
```