# Замена открытого exe файла

Tags: c#, .net, copy

имеется две папки, одна папка (first) с файлом Test.exe (в ней файл не запущен),а есть вторая папка (dest) , из которой запущена программа "Test.exe", возможен ли вариант копирования программы из папки first , в папку dest с заменой файла Test.exe? Пробовал разными методами, File.Copy  - не копирует с заменой при открытом процессе, попробовал FileStream ,но тоже не получилось, размер файла 10 мб.

```
using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(first, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
using (FileStream destStream = new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                        {
                            const int BUFFER_SIZE = 70000;
                            byte[] buf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                            for (; ; )
                            {
                                int bytesRead = sourceStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                                if (bytesRead == 0) break;
                                destStream.Write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: если вы хотите обновлять приложение, то можно сделать через второй exe файл. Первый запускает его, сам закрывается. Второй обновляет первый, запускает его, а сам закрывается

Comment: В операционной системе Windows, если файл запущен, вы его можете только переименовать. Правда лично у меня это работало не всегда. То есть, вы можете, например `Test.exe` переименовать в `Test.exe.old`, а на освободившееся место поместить другой файл. Но тут думаю понимаете, что для применения изменений, программу надо перезапустить, а после перезапуска, можно удалить `.old` файл.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а подскажите пожалуйста, как можно переименовать файл в другой папке? Через Powershell у меня есть скрипт,через него получается, попробовал как тут, не получилось https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1002831/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8

Comment: `File.Move("старый путь к файлу", "новый путь к файлу");` (пример: `File.Move("C://File.exe" "C://File.exe.old");`)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо,а если заранее не известны файлы с одинаковыми именами?

Comment: Ну так узнайте эти файлы, я вам не ванга ведь, чтоб знать, что именно вы там делаете и как) В вопросе у вас "как заменить один файл на другой, если сам файл запущен", я вам сказал "лайфхак", который иногда помогает, а дальше уже, давайте сами, подстраивайте все под свои цели.

Comment: Тогда это не лайфхак,если все заведомо известно, можно переименовать,для того чтобы конфликты не возникали

Comment: А как вы собираетесь заменить файл, о котором ничего не знаете (путь, название)? Вот узнайте сначала это все, а затем пробуйте заменять, предварительно переименовав оригинал в что угодно, хоть `asdfdsgjfdhgfg`, главное освободить старое название, а затем копируйте/переносите туда другой файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, это невозможно.

Чтобы подменить исполняемый файл, приложение сначала надо закрыть.

Comment: подскажите возможно ли тогда ,когда я подключаюсь по "\\192.168.1.1\d$\Dir";  переименовать файлы, если при копировании содержаться файлы с одинаковым названием? К примеру копирую из папки File в папку Dir , видя одинаковое название при копировании, то к старому файлу дописывалось бы .backup и копировался бы уже новый файл

Comment: @Alex `if (File.Exists(path)) File.Copy(path, path + ".backup");` ну или `File.Move`, вроде просто должно было быть